# Looping Code is not moving through the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in my database that pulls data from a query to calculate the subassembly parts needed on a weekly basis and with the click of the "complete" button the required components should be moved into and out of inventory yet nothing happens when the complete button is clicked. The code should loop through and move all the parts but nothing happens.

I have stepped through to see if there are any errors and corrected a few syntax errors but that is all I have done.

```vb
Private Sub Command96_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim ctln
    Dim Qty As Double
    Dim db As DAO.Database
        Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                Select Case ctl.ControlName
                    Case ctl Like "*Q"
                        ctln = Me.Controls(Right(ctl, Len(ctl) - 1))
                        If Not IsNull(DLookup("[In]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                            num = DLookup("[In]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "' AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "") + ctl
                        Else
                            num = ctl
                        End If
                        If Not IsNull(DLookup("[PartNum]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Inventory] " _
                                            & "SET [In] = " & num & " " _
                                            & "WHERE [PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "", dbFailOnError
                        Else
                            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Inventory] " _
                                            & "VALUES ('" & ctln & "'," & Me.YearNum & "," & Me.WeekNum & "," & num & ",0)", dbFailOnError
                        End If

                        num = 0

                        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT UsedPartNum, (Quantity * " & ctl & ") AS Used FROM SubPartsUsed WHERE FinPartNum = '" & PartNum & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
                        If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
                            rs.MoveFirst
                            Do Until rs.EOF = True
                                If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Out]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                                    num = DLookup("[Out]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "' AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "") + rs!Used
                                Else
                                    num = rs!Used
                                End If
                                If Not IsNull(DLookup("[PartNum]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                                    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Inventory] " _
                                                    & "SET [Out] = " & num & " " _
                                                    & "WHERE [PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & ""
                                Else
                                    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Inventory] " _
                                                    & "VALUES ('" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'," & Me.YearNum & "," & Me.WeekNum & ",0," & num & ")"
                                End If
                                rs.MoveNext
                            Loop
                        End If
                        rs.Close
                        Set rs = Nothing
                End Select
        End Select
```

I expect the parts to be entered into inventory as complete subassembly parts and the components to make them should be removed from inventory.

Comment: At a quick glance, your code looks OK. What I would do next is take all of the SQL statements in your code, and run them separately in query windows. That way, you can see if the SQL is doing what you expect. Once you know the SQL is working, fixing the code should be easy.

Comment: Specify field names in the INSERT action. Really should not save aggregate calcs. Enter transaction records then calculate net balance from data.

Comment: My abilities are "limited" to say the least, I am grateful for all of the help. I used debug.print after the first select case and it showed all of the text boxes. However I tried the same thing after the second select case (like "*Q") and it didn't show any result. So does that mean that I can assume the problem lies with using like Q to identify the quantities I want to move? If so I don't know what the alternative would be. The quantities are identified as part attribute with a Q at the end. Example: a right terminal is (RTerm), a right terminal quantity (RTermQ).

Comment: So I slipped in a Debug.Print right above "Select Case ctl.ControlName" to show me what it's seeing in the immediate window and I get a value for all fields except Qty. Could this be why both ctl and ctln are always empty? I'm at a complete loss as to where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

Code is done by high professional specialist in VBA, many shortcuts for code executing. It could be difficult for new VBA programmer to correct this code, so I think:

- first step  should be adding `Debug.Print code executed here at line number XXX` in order to study what lines are executed, and if their execution is done as assumpted.
- After that, if there is OK with code logic, `Debug.Print` all SQL statements, that are generated. So you can check their correctness through executing in query designer

E.g.:

```
Private Sub Command96_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim ctln
Dim Qty As Double
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Debug.Pring "looping through controls"
        Case "TextBox"
            Select Case ctl.ControlName
                Case ctl Like "*Q"
                    Debug.Pring "Control with Q letter is found"
                    ctln = Me.Controls(Right(ctl, Len(ctl) - 1))
                    If Not IsNull(DLookup("[In]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                        Debug.Print "Num is DLookuped"
                        num = DLookup("[In]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "' AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "") + ctl
                    Else
                        num = ctl
                    End If
                    If Not IsNull(DLookup("[PartNum]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                        Debug.Print "Executing Update Query for not null dlookup"
                        sSQL = "UPDATE [Inventory] " _
                                        & "SET [In] = " & num & " " _
                                        & "WHERE [PartNum] = '" & ctln & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & ""
                        Debug.Print sSQL
                        CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

                    Else
                        Debug.Print "Executing Update Query for null dlookup"
                        sSQL = "INSERT INTO [Inventory] " _
                                        & "VALUES ('" & ctln & "'," & Me.YearNum & "," & Me.WeekNum & "," & num & ",0)"
                        Debug.Print sSQL
                        CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
                    End If

                    num = 0

                    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT UsedPartNum, (Quantity * " & ctl & ") AS Used FROM SubPartsUsed WHERE FinPartNum = '" & PartNum & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
                    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
                        Debug.Print "Beginning action for each record in PartNum select query"
                        rs.MoveFirst
                        Do Until rs.EOF = True
                            If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Out]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                                Debug.Print "Executing Dlookup for element in PartNum select query"
                                num = DLookup("[Out]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "' AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "") + rs!Used

                            Else
                                num = rs!Used
                            End If
                            If Not IsNull(DLookup("[PartNum]", "[Inventory]", "[PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & "")) Then
                                Debug.Print "Executing Update for not null DLookup element in PartNum select query"
                                sSQL = "UPDATE [Inventory] " _
                                                & "SET [Out] = " & num & " " _
                                                & "WHERE [PartNum] = '" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'AND [YearNum] = " & Me.YearNum & " AND [WeekNum] = " & Me.WeekNum & ""
                                Debug.Print sSQL
                                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
                            Else
                                Debug.Print "Executing Update for  null DLookup element in PartNum select query"
                                sSQL = "INSERT INTO [Inventory] " _
                                                & "VALUES ('" & rs!UsedPartNum & "'," & Me.YearNum & "," & Me.WeekNum & ",0," & num & ")"
                                Debug.Print sSQL
                                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
                            End If
                            rs.MoveNext
                        Loop
                    End If
                    rs.Close
                    Set rs = Nothing
            End Select
    End Select
```

In this case you should study your Immediate windows (openes by `Ctrl` + `G`) to see, what is the execution plan, and what SQL texts are generated, and check all of them.

Otherwise, there is too many your business specific logics in this code, and it is quite impossible to understand program behavior. Maybe such behavior is assumpted, due to business logics? Many, many questions

Comment: Other option is to move execution parts and DLookups to separate functions, in would be easier to debug them further.

Comment: Irony should be marked ("Code is done by high professional specialist in VBA") ;)

Comment: So it is written in short way, but reading and debuggin complicated. One needs advanced knowledge of VBA for this.. but I don't like to use such approach, better more lines but modular structure of several interconnected functions.

Comment: Change "done by" to "done for" and I agree!  Readability and reduced complexity are keys to maintainability and extraction may be more code first, but the trick is to reuse it. Also shows lack of knowledge on`CurrenDb and query parameters (besides the questionable db desgin).

Answer (score 0):

Hit the F9 key over, and over, and over, until you see what the problem is.  Also, leverage 'Add Watch' to see what values are passed to which variables.  That should help immensely.  Finally, if this is done by a professional, why are you using: '`Command96_Click()`'?  Of course that's not the problem, but it's not helping either.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I used the add watch and I did see some messages regarding values being <out of context>  but I am afraid interpreting how to solve that is a bit beyond my understanding at this point

Comment: It's very customized code.  I don't think it will be possible, or certainly not easy, to reproduce your scenario.  Can you share the file or is it confidential?  Stepping through the code in your actual database should be pretty trivial.

Comment: Thanks Asher, I will check on that and if I'm allowed I will send you the file to take a look at

Comment: Make sure you have permission to do that!!  I have heard of people being fired for sharing confidential information.  Although, I think the company was just cutting back, because the 'confidential' information that was shared was readily available to anyone who works in the financial sector, or anyone who has access to the Internet and an interest in using financial data.  I have used this file sharing service in the past: https://www.mediafire.com/

There are MANY others out there just like it.

Comment: Asher, I did get permission. I had to change some customer information first but I have uploaded the file to my mediafire account. I just need somewhere I can send the link for you to access the file. Thank you so much for offering to help me with this.

Comment: I still need the help on this if your still able to do it.

Comment: rms7272 at gmail dot com

Comment: Thanks again. I sent you the link to the file